The minimal primary decomposition of zero ideal of cartesian product

Question: Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be two commutative rings, and $M_1$ and $M_2$ be coprimary $R_1$-module and $R_2$-module respectively. Find the minimal primary decomposition of $0$ as a submodule of $\left(R_1 \times R_2 \right)$-module $M_1 \times M_2$.

My proof goes as follows. I attempt the explain ${\rm Ass} (M_1 \times M_2)$ is just ${\rm Ass} (M_1) \times {\rm Ass}(M_2)$. Suppose ${\rm Ass}(M_i) = \left\{ P_i^0 \right\}$. Prime ideals of $R_1 \times R_2$ are always of the form $P_1 \times P_2$, where $P_1$ and $P_2$ are prime ideals of $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively.
Consider $P = (P_1,P_2) \in {\rm Ass} \left( M_1 \times M_2  \right)$. There exists $x = (x_1,x_2) \in M_1 \times M_2$ such that $P = {\rm ann}(x)$ by definition. That is, for $r \in R_1 \times R_2$, $rx = 0$ if and only if $r \in P$. While $rx = 0$ indicates $r_1x_1 = 0$ and $r_2x_2 = 0$, hence $P_i \in {\rm ann}(x_i) = {\rm Ass} (M_i)$, and therefore $P_i = P_i^0$. It is also clear that suppose $P_i^0 = {\rm ann} (x_i^0)$, then $P^0 := P_1^0 \times P_2^0 = {\rm ann}((x_1^0, x_2^0))$. Therefore $0$ is $P^0$-primary submodule of $M_1 \times M_2$ and therefore the minimal primary decomposition of $0$ is exactly itself.
I doubt that my result is weird. Could you explain where I make a mistake or the fact is just that weird? Any comment is appreciated.
